# Changing Image by pressing jbutton java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

Hello I am having trouble with my code and I have been trying to figure out what is wrong for a few days and looked at somewhat relevant programs for help and can not figure it out. The program is supposed to change the the image of a traffic light based on what button you press: red, yellow, or green. There are 3 classes. I am running the program in eclipse.
CLass 1 trafficLight that contains the main method:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class trafficLight
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Creates and displays the main program frame.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("CHANGE TRAFFIC LIGHT");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      trafficLightPanel lights = new trafficLightPanel();
      trafficLightControls controls = new trafficLightControls(lights);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
      panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));



      panel.add(Box.createRigidArea (new Dimension (0, 20)));
      panel.add(lights);
      panel.add(Box.createRigidArea (new Dimension (0, 10)));
      panel.add(controls);
      panel.add(Box.createRigidArea (new Dimension (0, 10)));

      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

The second class trafficLightPanel that contain the imageicons part:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class trafficLightPanel extends JPanel
{
    public int count, redCount, yellowCount, greenCount;
    private ImageIcon none, red, yellow, green;
    private JLabel imageLabel;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor: Sets up the images and the initial state.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public trafficLightPanel()
    {

        none = new ImageIcon("nonePic.png");
        red = new ImageIcon("redPic.png");
        yellow = new ImageIcon("yellowPic.png");
        green = new ImageIcon("greenPic.png");
        setBackground(Color.black);
        redCount = 1; yellowCount = 2; greenCount = 3;

        imageLabel = new JLabel(none);

        add(imageLabel);

    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Paints the panel using the appropriate image.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        if (count == redCount)
        {
            imageLabel.setIcon(red);
        }
        if (count == yellowCount)
        {
            imageLabel.setIcon(yellow);
        }
        if (count == greenCount)
        {
            imageLabel.setIcon(green);
        }
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets the status of the traffic light.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public void setCount(int newCount)
    {
         count = newCount;
    }
}
```

The third class trafficLightControls containing the jbuttons:

```
//********************************************************************
// Represents the control panel for the traffic light program.
//********************************************************************
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class trafficLightControls extends JPanel
{
    private trafficLightPanel lights;
    private JButton red, yellow, green;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Sets up the traffic light control panel.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    public trafficLightControls(trafficLightPanel lightPanel)
    {
            lights = lightPanel;
            red = new JButton("RED");
            red.addActionListener(new redListener());
            yellow = new JButton("YELLOW");
            yellow.addActionListener(new yellowListener());
            green = new JButton("GREEN");
            green.addActionListener(new greenListener());

            setBackground(Color.black);
            add(red);
            add(yellow);
            add(green);

    }
    //*****************************************************************
    // Represents the listener for the red button.
    //*****************************************************************
    private class redListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        // sets count to redCount and repaints the lights panel.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            lights.setCount(lights.redCount);
            lights.repaint();
        }
    }
    //*****************************************************************
    //Represents the listener for the yellow button.
    //*****************************************************************
    private class yellowListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //sets count to yellowCount and repaints the lights panel.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            lights.setCount(lights.yellowCount);
            lights.repaint();
        }
    }
    //*****************************************************************
    //Represents the listener for the green button.
    //*****************************************************************
    private class greenListener implements ActionListener
    {
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        //sets count to green count and repaints the lights panel.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            lights.setCount(lights.greenCount);
            lights.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: nonePic.png the non lit up traffic light image]
[image: redPic.png of traffic light lit up with red]
[image: yellowPic.png]
[image: greenPic.png]

Each time I click a button it is supposed to set the count in the trafficLightPanel object, lights, to the count that corresponds to the color, then based on the count the image is supposed to be replaced by the corresponding image. The components are all put together with a box layout.

For some reason only red will work... It starts out displaying the nonePic, the one without any light, and when I click red it displays redPic. If I click on any before or after clicking RED button, the others do not display. If I click one of the others first then RED button, red can still display for some reason. All images are in the root folder(is this the correct name?), the one containing the src and bin folders.

I thought maybe something was wrong with the count, and I tried doing something like adding a jLabel that would display the count each time into the program with the box layout but it does not display anything(this attempt is not in the code). I also tried putting the jLabel into the trafficLightControls class and adding it along with the add(red) add(yellow).... but it would not display anything. Another thing I tried was to change the text of the buttons each time to displaying the color with the count as an alternative to the jLabel attempt. I tried using .setText("") method like red.setText("") in the listener class for red. I would appreciate it if anyone could explain how to add a jLabel and change the text of the button as I have described in this particular little paragraph, as it is something I would like to know how to do to for future reference, though it is not necessary to solving my problem so its ok to not help out with this little paragraph.

Thank you very much for any help anyone offers!

edit: (I am sorry I left in remnants of my attempts at making jLabels to test the code but I removed them, though they did not affect the code I believe, I attempted to use them because of my problem. I am very sorry if this confused anyone)

Comment: Your post is waaay too long, I strongly suggest shortening it as much as possible.

Comment: I do not think this question can be solved without posting everything.

Comment: Don't do your `setIcon(...)` within paintComponent! That should go in the ActionListener. The paintComponent method is for painting only, and you're not really doing painting here, just swapping icons.

Comment: @Dominick In that case, you're wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you Hover craft I will work on it

Comment: Or if not in actionPerformed then in the `setCount(...)` method which is called by actionPerformed. Either way the actionPerformed should trigger the code's calling `setIcon(...)` on the label.

Comment: I was just basing this on an example in slides for my class. It changes a light bulb between being on and off. It used something like this but used a boolean on instead of count and had the same format. I thought the .repaint int the trafficLightControls did the painting once icons were swapped.

Comment: There is no need to call `repaint()` when swapping icons.

Comment: Please see edits to answer. Ask if any questions about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call `repaint()` and you shouldn't override `paintComponent` if all you're doing is swapping ImageIcons. Simply call `setIcon(...)` on your JLabel is all that is needed. The model will trigger a repainting of the view itself.

Getting rid of your paintComponent override and changing setCount to something as simple as this could work:

```
public void setCount(int newCount) {
    count = newCount;
    Icon icon = null;
    switch (count) {
    case 1:
        icon = red;
        break;
    case 2:
        icon = yellow;
        break;
    case 3: 
        icon = green;
        break;
    default:
        icon = null;
        break;
    }
    imageLabel.setIcon(icon);
}
```

For example, my MCVE, one that uses an enum and a Map to simplify the code a bit.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Traff2 extends JPanel {
    public Traff2() {
        Traff2LightPanel lightPanel = new Traff2LightPanel();
        Traff2LightControlsPanel controlsPanel = new Traff2LightControlsPanel(lightPanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(lightPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(controlsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Traff2 mainPanel = new Traff2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Traffic");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
enum Light {
    NONE(""), RED("Red"), YELLOW("Yellow"), GREEN("Green");

    private String text;

    private Light(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Traff2LightPanel extends JPanel {
    private Map<Light, Icon> lightColorMap = new EnumMap<>(Light.class);
    private JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
    private Light light = Light.NONE;

    public Traff2LightPanel() {
        // fill the map
        lightColorMap.put(Light.NONE, new ImageIcon("nonePic.png"));
        lightColorMap.put(Light.RED, new ImageIcon("redPic.png"));
        lightColorMap.put(Light.YELLOW, new ImageIcon("yellowPic.png"));
        lightColorMap.put(Light.GREEN, new ImageIcon("greenPic.png"));

        imageLabel.setIcon(lightColorMap.get(Light.NONE));
        add(imageLabel);
    }

    // when changing the light field, 
    // also set the ImageIcon
    public void setLight(Light light) {
        this.light = light;
        imageLabel.setIcon(lightColorMap.get(light));
    }

    public Light getLight() {
        return light;
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Traff2LightControlsPanel extends JPanel {
    private Traff2LightPanel lightPanel;

    public Traff2LightControlsPanel(Traff2LightPanel lightPanel) {
        this.lightPanel = lightPanel;
        for (Light light : Light.values()) {
            if (light == Light.NONE) {
                continue;
            }
            add(new JButton(new LightAction(light)));
        }
    }

    // use an AbstractAction... 
    // like an ActionListener on "steroids"
    private class LightAction extends AbstractAction {
        private Light light;

        public LightAction(Light light) {
            super(light.getText());
            this.light = light;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            lightPanel.setLight(light);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate what you typed out but I have never used enum or maps and some other code you used and this code is very confusing to me.

Comment: I tried  commenting out the if(count... )... part of the paint component leaving only super.paintComponent(page) and moved the if(count...) part to the setCount method as well as taking out the repaint part from the button action listeners, but it still did not work. I then tried getting rid of the count method completely and just put lights.imageLabel.setIcon(lights.red); into the action listeners after making everything public in the trafficLightPanel class and it still did not work. I am still confused as to how to implement what you are telling me into my program.

Comment: @Dominick: what exactly is your code showing? Is it showing any image at all?

Comment: Could you help me make my program work without changing it drastically and keeping it very similar in terms of complexity and the types of methods used. It is still doing the exact same thing... only red works for some reason

Comment: @Dominick: You just need to improve the setCount method and get rid of the paintComponent override. see edit at top.

Comment: Only red works no matter how I have tried to change the program even before seeking help on here. And the way the program is functioning never changes. I think the problem might have to with how the program searches for the images i made. Like since red was declared first the program only took in red like normal then after that something changed with the other images not allowing them to be found as I would like.

Comment: I tried doing what you had said to do with the switch and it still did not work. what part of the paintComponent am I supposed to be keeping? only the super.paintComponent(page) part?

Comment: @Dominick: delete **all** of paintComponent as it is completely unnecessary and potentially dangerous. If none is working, then time to do some debugging -- find out if your program is accurately reading your images into ImageIcons to start with. In the code where you read in the images, display each ImageIcon in a JOptionPane (pass the icon as the 2nd parameter of a `JOptionPane.showMessage(null, icon);` call and make sure.

Comment: ahh. I am so sorry I feel like I wasted your time. I got it to work by creating a new java project and copy pasting everything into the new project. I think the problem was when I first tried to find out where to put images, someone in a different thread said put in a new source file and then that didnt work so I put it into the root folder and deleted the new source file I made. There was a red ! next to my project. The problem had to do with that and how the file was trying to find the images. Maybe red was permanently set to always be the one to work only or something but now it works.

Comment: also I tried putting all my code back to the way it was like in my original code, since like I said before this is based off the example in the slides for my class and that works. I left the if(count) part in the paint component and still used repaint and it worked. I was thinking it would be weird that we would get examples that are not supposed to work.  It also seems to work when I take away the repaint and put the if(count...) part in the setcount method like you said for some reason.

Comment: I also took away the paint component completely and it worked still.

Comment: ok so I found that you can use the paint component and have the if(count ==...) part in it only if you use repaint, like in the example about a lightbulb i mentioned. If you comment out repaint in the button listeners, it will not work. But if you completely take away the paintcomponent and transfer the if(count==...) part to the setCount method the program will work without repaint. like you were talking about. Thank you very much for helping me with all of this. I am very sorry again.